# Why are there separate "trie_node" and "trie" structures?

Tags: c++, c, string, tree, trie

I have read the following implementation for implementing trie.

```
typedef struct trie_node trie_node_t;
struct trie_node 
{
int value;
trie_node_t *children[ALPHABET_SIZE];
};

// trie ADT
typedef struct trie trie_t;
struct trie 
{
trie_node_t *root;
int count; 
};
```

I dont understand why there are two structures when we can have just one with an array of pointers and a value type. Please help.!

Comment: You can certainly do it that way. The root of a trie typically has the opening alphabet to the splay below. You could alternatively just use a `trie_node` for this and ignore the value. However a custom root node allows you to have a place to stash trie-wide goodies and potentially helpful shortcuts (ex: `count` member).

Comment: @WhozCraig Can you explain the above declaration . This is what I got. trie_node has value and 26 pointer( english). I we want we can have a count that tells how many words are formed till that prefix.  Why to use like that.!

Comment: given only the declaration, i cannot say what `count` is for definitively. Since `root` is not a full alphabet-sized array of prefix node pointers, I can only imagine `count` is the dynamic count of that dynamic array. (which is a somewhat stupid design imho, since the only node in this design that is space-efficient by minimizing unnecessary pointers seems to be the root, of which there is one, rather than the general trie-node, of which there are N).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Short answer**

`trie_node_t` is type of each node inside (linked into a) trie.

`trie_t` is type of each trie.

**Usage**

Possible usage may be

```
trie_t tr1, tr2;  /* Create 2 tries */

addstring(&tr1, "baseball");   /* This adds multiple nodes to existing trie */
addstring(&tr1, "basketball");

addstring(&tr2, "rock");
addstring(&tr2, "rocket");
addstring(&tr2, "rob");
```

Author used 2 structure possibly because it makes the things more modular and manageable and ease the dynamic allocation.

**Visualization**

```
 +--------+
 |  tr2   |    trie_t
 +---+----+
     |
   +-+-+
   | r |       trie_node_t
   +-+-+
     |
   +-+-+
   | o |       trie_node_t
   +-+-+
    / \
   /   \
+-+-+ +-+-+
| b*| | c |    both trie_node_t
+---+ +-+-+
        |
      +-+-+
      | k*|    trie_node_t
      +-+-+
        |
      +-+-+
      | e |    trie_node_t
      +-+-+
        |
      +-+-+
      | t*|    trie_node_t
      +---+
(* means count is not zero)
```

**Finally**

Trie (or other data structure for example linked list) is just an idea, and implementation may vary.

For example a linked list may be implemented as an array (keeping index of next item as link and keeping a special number for last) or as node type and list type where list type contains pointer to head. Former implementation may be easy to understand, implement and debug, while later implementation exploits dynamic allocation better. An implementation may be good for one purpose while may not be as suitable for other purpose.

Comment: rng..58 submitted an array based implementation trie in [solution of Problem C during Round 1B 2013 of google code jam](http://code.google.com/codejam/contest/scoreboard?c=2434486#vf=1)

Comment: This means there can be only one trie_t for a given set of strings that we are implementing.??

Comment: Yes, if you have only 1 trie (let's call it dictionary). You add multiple strings to it. There will be 1 `trie_t`, and each string added may create 0 or 1 or more nodes of type `trie_node_t` and link it into existing trie.